# Realm Update failed - Android

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm using realm for my android apps, So I want to update my Bill object using the same Primary key, but ended with

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: com.example.rikirikmen.billsplit, PID: 22045
>                                                                                     io.realm.exceptions.RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already
>   exists: 1

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        Bill updateBill = realm.where(Bill.class).equalTo("Bill_ID", bill).findFirst();
                        DetailMenu menu = realm.createObject(DetailMenu.class);

                        menu.setMenuID(MenuID);
                        menu.setMenuName(String.valueOf(menuName.getText()));
                        menu.setMenuPrice(Price);
                        menu.setQuantity(Qty);
                        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getPersonMenuObjList().size(); i++) {
                            PersonInMenu pim = realm.createObject(PersonInMenu.class);
                            pim.setPersonID(adapter.getPersonMenuObjList().get(i).getPersonID());
                            pim.setStatus(adapter.getPersonMenuObjList().get(i).isStatus());
                            menu.personInMenus.add(pim);
                        }

                        updateBill.detailmenu.add(menu);
                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(updateBill);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: what do you mean ? i need to createobject? the object already created in other activity before.. i just want to update the object.

Comment: what do you mean inside transaction ? actually realm has create a new method realm.executetransaction for replacing realm.begintransaction and commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Do this](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2939#issuecomment-224675528):

```
           realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    Bill updateBill = realm.where(Bill.class).equalTo("Bill_ID", bill).findFirst();
                    DetailMenu menu = new DetailMenu();
                    RealmList<PersonInMenu> personInMenus = new RealmList<>(); //added line
                    menu.personInMenus = personInMenus; //added line
                    menu.setMenuID(MenuID);
                    menu.setMenuName(String.valueOf(menuName.getText()));
                    menu.setMenuPrice(Price);
                    menu.setQuantity(Qty);
                    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getPersonMenuObjList().size(); i++) {
                        PersonInMenu pim = new PersonInMenu();
                        pim.setPersonID(adapter.getPersonMenuObjList().get(i).getPersonID());
                        pim.setStatus(adapter.getPersonMenuObjList().get(i).isStatus());
                        menu.personInMenus.add(pim);
                    }

                    updateBill.detailmenu.add(menu);
                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(updateBill);
                }
            });
```

Although if you're hesitant about saving detached objects to the Realm through `copyToRealmOrUpdate()`, then use the [appropriate override for `createObject()` which actually takes a primary key as its second parameter](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#createObject-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-).

If you use `createObject(clazz, primaryKey)` then you won't need `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` in this case.

Comment: thankyou for your advice, actually i dont know its working or not.. i just got new error

`Process: com.example.rikirikmen.billsplit, PID: 31338 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean io.realm.RealmList.add(io.realm.RealmModel)' on a null object reference at com.example.rikirikmen.billsplit.DialogActivity$1$1.execute(DialogActivity.java:101)`

Comment: my object are filled, i dont know where is wrong.
here is the log

`06-11 18:02:56.785 31338-31338/com.example.rikirikmen.billsplit I/Object: 6 true
06-11 18:02:56.785 31338-31338/com.example.rikirikmen.billsplit I/Object: 7 true
06-11 18:02:56.785 31338-31338/com.example.rikirikmen.billsplit I/Object: 8 false
06-11 18:02:56.785 31338-31338/com.example.rikirikmen.billsplit I/Object: 9 false
06-11 18:02:56.785 31338-31338/com.example.rikirikmen.billsplit I/Object: 10 false`

Comment: The `personInMenus` is null by default and I forgot to set it to be a `RealmList<T>`, added modified code

Comment: thankyou EpicPandaForce, you are Realm Master haha.. marked it as answer